# Cant put seperator while binding views

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm building a caller app that has a contacts page
The contacts I'm getting using a cursor and using that cursor in **onBindViewHolder**
I want to put a separator between different letter contacts
the problem is that I can't find a way to add a "run" on **onBindViewHolder** so that I inflate a separatorHolder and then the cursor gets back to the same spot it was.

I tried using two different view types but since I'm fetching the contacts from the device with a cursor I have no way to add the separators to the cursor.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v;
    switch (viewType) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_ITEM:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_contact, parent, false);
            return new ContactHolder(v);
        case VIEW_TYPE_SEPERATOR:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_separator, parent, false);
            return new SeparatorHolder(v);
        default:
            v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.item_contact, parent, false);
            return new ContactHolder(v);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {
    switch (viewHolder.getItemViewType()) {
        case VIEW_TYPE_ITEM:
            ContactHolder contactHolder = (ContactHolder) viewHolder;
            Contact contact = new Contact(cursor);
            String contactName = contact.getName();
            String contactNumber = contact.getMainPhoneNumber();
            String formattedNumber =
                    Utilities.formatPhoneNumber(contactNumber);

            contactHolder.name.setText(contactName);
            contactHolder.number.setText(formattedNumber);

            if (contact.getPhotoUri() == null) {
                contactHolder.photo.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                contactHolder.photoPlaceholder.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                contactHolder.photo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                contactHolder.photoPlaceholder.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                contactHolder.photo.setImageURI(Uri.parse(contact.getPhotoUri()));
            }

            if (mOnContactSelectedListener != null) {
                contactHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v ->
                        mOnContactSelectedListener.onContactSelected(contactNumber));
            }
            break;
        case VIEW_TYPE_SEPERATOR:
            SeparatorHolder separatorHolder = (SeparatorHolder)
                    viewHolder;

            separatorHolder.text.setText(separator);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you override the getItemViewType ? in recycler Adapter?

Comment: @ArbazPirwani yes but getItemViewType just goes through the same list of contacts to which i cant add placement list that will be the separators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things - getItemCount and getItemViewType.

getItemCount - It should return the total items(no of contacts + no of separators).
Write some logic to find this.(calculate the total different starting letters, subtract by 1 , gives you separator count)

getItemViewType - Here, you should validate whether this should be a contact or separator, and send those type.(Get the previous one and check first letter)

But, needs to be cautious on the logic.

Comment: But the problem is that im using a cursor and i dont have the data saved, it gets passed straight from the device memory, wont it be a problem?

Comment: It is not a problem. cursor.getCount() will give you the data count. cursor is just a data container adderess.